# Adding arrows to a diagram using diagram chasing preserves the commutativity

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

It is true that if we enlarge a commutative diagram of modules adding an arrow constructed by diagram chasing, then the diagram remains commutative?

I can prove this in some particular cases but I'm not sure if it is true in general.

Edit: It seems important to specify better what I understand by diagram chasing.

Let's say that the morphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ has been obtained from diagram chasing if there exist a sequence $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ of morphisms of the diagram and $e_1,...,e_n\in \{1,-1\}$ such that $\{f(x)\}=\alpha_1^{e_1}(\alpha_2^{e_2}(...(\alpha^{e_n}(\{x\}))...))$   $\forall x\in M$.

So for example, with this definition, the map defined by the firt isomorphism theorem has been obtained by diagram chasing because $$\{\bar{f}(x)\}=f(\pi^{-1}(\{x\})) \  \ \forall x\in G/\ker(f)$$.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: What does arrow constructed by diagram chasing mean?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy. Now I put what I understand for diagram chasing.

Comment: @HeinrichD why do you say that preimage sets don't work? It seems clear that this is what the OP meant, and with this reading his construction of the maps in the first isomorphism theorem is correct...

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything to prove here? If you take a square, with maps along rows called $r_1$ and $r_2$, and maps down columns called $c_1$ and $c_2$, then saying "the square commutes" is the same statement as $c_2 \circ r_1 = r_2 \circ c_1$. If you "add the diagonal" arrow to the square, you would surely defined it to be $c_2 \circ r_1$ (or equivalently, $r_2 \circ c_1$). So the resulting diagram still commutes.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well. Please read the edit.